# Wildcard filter for reading jpg and png files in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-extension

how can i modify this row in order to make matlab read png files also?

This is my code

```
dir(fullfile(directory, '*.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
listing = [ dir(fullfile(directory, '*.jpg')) ; dir(fullfile(directory, '*.png'))];
```